# Как найти кратчайший путь с минимальным количеством поворотов?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть двухмерный список grid который является картой местности. Где 1 это стена а 0 пустота. Как найти кратчайший путь с минимальным количеством поворотов ?

В данном примере 1 это оранжевая стена а 0 черная пустота:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красная линия это то как путь должен быть проложен.
А белая как он проложен.

Код можно взять с https://github.com/StanislavPetrovV/Python-Dijkstra-BFS-A-star
файл **bfs_pygame_control.py**

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться динамическим программированием.

Comment: Путь может быть не оптимален, насколько я понимаю, но можете идти только вправо и вниз и для каждой клетки считать сколько поворотов уже использовано для нее для конкретного пути и считать по минимуму таких поворотов

Comment: Так кратчайший путь или с минимальным количеством поворотов?

Comment: Можете использовать обычный bfs, но только каждую вершину графа нужно разделить на 4 отдельных подвершины, каждая из которых указывает на конкретное направление. Таким образом, вы имеете всего три перехода из каждой вершины: повернуть налево/направо и пойти вперед. Причем повороты имеют единичный вес, а движение нулевой. С таким графом справится 0-1 bfs.
Если же необходим кратчайший из минимальных путей, то, кажется, нужен любой алгоритм поиска кратчайшего пути на взвешенном графе. Тогда весом ребра будет пара (вес типа, расстояние типа), а расстоянием (min rotate, min dist).

Comment: EzikBro -  Звучит интересно, но как бы это реализовать ?

Comment: Владислав Харламов - Ни только вправо и вниз, главное чтоб был кратчайший путь и минимальное количество поворотов

Comment: tym32167 - да с минимальным количеством поворотов